# Setting the current date into a variable in a Script in bash

Tags: bash, date, procmail

So for the life of me I cannot figure out why my script will not take my date command as a variable.  I have a script that is run every time a message is received and `procmail` filters specific messages by their subject line.  The script looks like this:

```
d=$(date +%Y%m%d)

:0 wc
* ^(From|subject).*xxx
| cat&>/xx/xx/xx/xx/MSG:$d && \
chmod xxx /xx/xx/xx/xx/MSG:$d && \
/xx/xx/xx/otherscript.sh /xx/xx/xx/xx/MSG:$d
```

I have run the date command plenty of times in other scripts and to `stdout` without any issue, so I am wondering if this is a `procmail` issue?  I have looked at a few different sites about this but still have not found a solution.  My end goal is to create unique file names as well as for organization purposes each time a new email comes in.

The other reason for me believing it has something to do with `procmail` is that it was working fine just 3 months ago (didn't change any files or permissions). I have even tried several variations (only showing a few examples):

```
 $'date +"%Y%m%d"'
 $(date)
 echo $(date)
```

I get a variety of files created ranging with it printing MSG:(date), MSG:(date ,etc. MSG:(date  appears to like it tries to read the variable but is getting cut off or the space between date and + is causing an issue.

And at the end of my script I send it to another script which also creates a new file with the date appended and it works just fine:

```
fileOut="/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.$v.$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S").xxx"
prints: xxx.YH8AcFV9.20160628-090506.txt
```

Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: The documentation I am seeing seems to indicate that: ``d=`date +"%Y%m%d"` `` should do the trick. Have you tried that?

Comment: Set `UMASK` instead of fiddling with `chmod` or, better yet, change your script so it reads from standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procmail does not support the modern POSIX shell command substitution syntax; you need to use backticks.

```
d=`date +%Y%m%d`  # or just date +%F
```

If you want to avoid invoking an external process, the `From_` pseudo-header contains a fresh date stamp on many architectures.

Comment: Appreciate it, didn't realize Procmail didn't use the same syntax.